# Position and spacing with inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I'm sure for most of you this is an easy one, however, I cannot seem to get my code to render correctly.  I have three elements @ 330px wide each, which I am trying to place "side by side" within a 1050px content area.  Only one of the elements is rendering on the correct "block" with the other two appearing below.  I am simply trying to place the three together spaced evenly across the content area with adequate space between them.  Due to the fact that one element(rss feed) will only render on my site, please look at my test page to further explain what I am talking about:  http://www.realtimehockey.net/testing.html

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer.

My Code

```
CSS

.box {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

HTML

<div class="box">

<div class="feedgrabbr_widget" id="fgid_882d7000d9e4e2c5832cdb9c6"     
float="right"></div>
<script> if (typeof(fg_widgets)==="undefined") fg_widgets = new     
Array();fg_widgets.push("fgid_882d7000d9e4e2c5832cdb9c6");</script>
<script src="http://www.feedgrabbr.com/widget/fgwidget.js"></script>

<iframe 
src="https://scorestream.com/widgets/iframe?widgetId=16476"
style="padding:0px;border:0px;width:330px;height:600px;max-height:600px;
display:inline-block"
title="Realtime sports scoreboard widget"
scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F 
%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Frealtimehockey&amp;width=330&amp;height=600&
amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&
amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block; width:330px;
height:600px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>


</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to do the first panel as a `<div>` instead of an `<iframe>` like the others? Or perhaps could they all be done as `<div>`'s?

Comment: I guess that's possible although I'm not sure exactly to go upon it.  I'm new to the coding world so, I'd probably end up making it worse.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.feedgrabbr_widget {
    width: 330px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This should correct the width and display for the first box which was actually rendering as a block element with a width of 663px from the chrome inspector.

Comment: Tried that @Stewartside and still no luck.  Still rendering the same way.  I appreciate the input though.

Comment: Got it.  I eliminated the ".box" before feedgrabbr and that did it, however, if you take a look at the test page, they are all still pretty jammed together.  How can I add a little space between the 3?  Thanks again.